# php question include an included file

Tags: php, xml, file, include

I got a problem about including a included file in PHP.

Project

- functions(folder) has a.php
- xml(folder) has b.xml
- index.php

This is my project structure(sorry about that, I can't post images).
I try to use "*index.php*" to include "*a.php*" while "*a.php*" is using "*b.xml*"

this is what i did on XAMPP and it works perfectly:

in *index.php*  I wrote: **include 'functions/a.php';**

in *a.php*      I wrote: **$xml->load('xml/b.xml')**;

However if I copy these to my Uni's apache server, it can't open this b.xml.
This is not permission because when i change to absolute path it works...

Thank you guys in advance:-)

Comment: when using includes it's often best to load the file from the path of the include file with with something like: `$xml->load(dirname(__FILE__).'/../xml/b.xml');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a.php you should refer to ../xml/b.xml if you use include
thing is, it depeneds on when $xml->load() is defined. if it's your own code then put the path relative to the definition. otherwise "../xml/b.xml" should work.

you can always to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but i myself like defining directories as constants (with absolute path) and using them around the project.

```
define('DIR_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/');
define('DIR_FUNCTIONS', DIR_ROOT . 'functions/');
define('DIR_XML', DIR_ROOT . 'xml/');
```

Comment: I would do it like this too, it's easier to just use absolute paths. However, I would use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. If using PHP 5.3.0 (or above), `__DIR__` does the same as above.

Comment: I tried your solution but does't work 
I think this specific problem is because of my uni's server configuration. Every student has an account, and we put our php project inside our account's .HTMLinfo directory. However, the Server root is in a different directory so that i can't use absolute path about $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but it works perfectly if use absolute path of my personal account... which is not the one I want to use...
thank you for your reply anyway

Comment: you can do dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) to see how to address the file in your main project directory, should do the trick

Comment: thanks everyone, finally I've solved the problem. I use dirname(__FILE__) and appending some other string as an absolute path to load the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to set the include path to your application's root directory; then you should be able to include files relative to this path.

Answer (score 0):

It's **always** better to use absolute paths, even if you have to construct it (e.g. `$XML_PATH = $PATH_TO_BASE . 'xml/b.xml';` )

If you can't do that, you should add xml's parent to your path.